# How to approximate integral resulting from physics problem?

Tags: integration, mathematical-physics, approximate-integration

### Setup

I'm taking a physics class and need to calculate (or approximate) a particular integral. Let
$$\Delta(x):= 1-(1-x)x \frac{p^2}{m^2},$$
where $p^2:= p_\mu p_\nu\eta^{\mu\nu}$ with $\eta$ being the Minkowski metric. I'd like to show that approximately
$$\int_0^1 dx\, \ln\left({\Delta(x)}\right)\propto \sqrt{1-\frac{4m^2}{p^2}}\ln\left(\frac{2m^2-p^2+\sqrt{p^2(p^2-m^2)}}{2m^2}\right).$$

### My attempt

My only idea was to Taylor the $\ln$. Assuming $p^2/m^2$ to be small we have
$$\ln(\Delta(x)) = \left(x^2-x\right)\frac{p^2}{m^2}+\frac{1}{2} (x-1) x \left(x-x^2\right)\left(\frac{p^2}{m^2}\right)^2 +O\left(\left({p^2}/{m^2}\right)^3\right).$$
Then
$$\begin{align*}
\int_0^1dx \ln\Delta(x) 
&\approx \int_0^1 dx\, \left[\left(x^2-x\right)\frac{p^2}{m^2}+\frac{1}{2} (x-1) x \left(x-x^2\right)\left(\frac{p^2}{m^2}\right)^2\right]\\
&= -\frac{1}{6}\frac{p^2}{m^2} - \frac{1}{60}\left(\frac{p^2}{m^2}\right)^2.
\end{align*}$$
This seems completely off, or at least way too crude of an approximation.. Unfortunately, I don't really have much experience with integration so I don't really have any other smart ideas or tricks up my sleeve...

P.S. I have no idea how to name this question properly. If the title doesn't fit, please feel free to edit it.

Comment: Do you know the range of $\Delta x$ or $\left(1-x\right)x\frac{p^2}{m^2}$?

Comment: @YNK When you say range, what exactly do you mean? The only thing I can associate with that are the integration boundaries which are given by $0$ and $1$.

Comment: I thought of using one of many series expansions for $\Delta x$, all of which have their own convergence region (or range). We cannot eliminate higher order terms of a series, unless it is converging. You new that, didn't you? For instance, there are three different series for $\ln \left(x\right)$. One of them is converging only in the rane $x \gt 0$ and another in $0 \lt x \le 2$. The convergence region of the third is $x \gt \frac{1}{2}$. So, now you know what I mean by range.

Comment: Something is not adding up. If $p^2$ were the Minkowski 4 norm, then $p^2=m^2$, making most of your terms vanish.

Comment: @NinadMunshi The momentum is not necessarly on-shell..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily have the exact result.

Let
$$I=\int_0^1\log \big[1-k (1-x) x\big]\,dx$$
$$1-k (1-x) x=k x^2-k x+1=k(x-a)(x-b)$$
$$\log \big[1-k (1-x) x\big]=\log(k)+\log(x-a)+\log(x-b)$$ Using integration by parts
$$J=\int \log(x-c)\,dx=(x-c) \log (x-c)-x+ C$$
$$K(c)=\int_0^1 \log(x-c)\,dx=-(c-1) \log (1-c)+c \log (-c)-1$$

Now, use the above for
$$a=\frac{k+\sqrt{k-4} \sqrt{k}}{2 k} \qquad \text{and} \qquad b=\frac{k-\sqrt{k-4} \sqrt{k}}{2 k}$$

**Edit**

Rearranging all the logarithms leads to the simple result
$$\int_0^1  \ln\left({\Delta(x)}\right)\,dx=\frac{2 \sqrt{4 m^2-p^2} }{p}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{p}{\sqrt{4 m^2-p^2}}\right)-2$$ which is exact and looks simpler then the looked for approximation.

Expanded as a infinite series, this gives
$$\int_0^1  \ln\left({\Delta(x)}\right)\,dx=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!\,(n+1)!}{(2 n+3)!}\,\left(\frac{p^2}{m^2}\right)^n$$ In your post, you wrote the first and second terms.

This is quickly convergence since
$$a_n=\frac{n!\,(n+1)!}{(2 n+3)!}\implies \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{n+1}{4 n+10}$$

Comment: Thank you! I'll try it out after lunch.

Comment: @Sito. In fact, the exact solution is simple. https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BLog%5B1-k*+x*%281-x%29%5D%2Cx%5D

Comment: Took me a while to push everything into the form I needed, but this works perfectly!

Comment: @Sito. Have a look at my edit